# Getting reference key after posting

Tags: php, oop, reference

after creating a post, its `post id` is a primary key. how do i get this `post id` and post it to a date time database table and its a reference key of this table

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        global $post;
        $post->user_id= $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $post->post_created_date = strip_zeros_from_date(date("Y-m-d"));
        $post->post_created_time = "int time ( void )";
        if ($post->createpost()){
            global $datetime;
            $datetime->post_id = ??? ;


            redirect_to('profile.php');
        } else {
            // Failure
            echo 'failed';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No idea what technology you're using, but assuming the `createpost` method returns the created post info, you can do something like this:

```
if ($newPost = $post->createpost()){
        global $datetime;
        $datetime->post_id = $newPost['id'];
        ...
```